# String has access to entire text file

Tags: java, input

I am working on a Java project that loosely simulates a search engine by converting the Gettysburg address from a text file into a linear-linked list of Word objects which contain a String of the word and the line position. I compare these against a hash table of ignorable words and then insert the considerable words into a binary search tree where the number of appearances is recorded if duplicates occur.

I have my hashing function and most of the tree-adding parts down but I am having an issue that I can't seem to figure out regarding my input:

When reading the Gettysburg address using BufferedReader.readLine(), after cleansing the String of punctuation that String seems to contain the entire text file though it was instantiated as line = br.readLine().

Here is the first few lines of getty.txt:

Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this
continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the
proposition that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in a

I have attached my code below for context.

```
private static ObjectList getWords(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    ObjectList wordList = new ObjectList();
    int lineCNT = 1;
    int positionCNT = 1;
    String line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    while(line != null)
    {
        line = line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", ""); // This somehow has access to the whole file String.
        System.out.println(line);
        String delims = "[\\W]+";
        String[] tokens = line.split(delims);
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(tokens[i]);
        }
        while(positionCNT-1 < tokens.length)
        {
            LinePosition linePosition = new LinePosition(lineCNT, positionCNT);
            Word word = new Word(tokens[positionCNT-1], linePosition);
            wordList.insert(word);
            positionCNT++;
        }
        line = br.readLine();
        lineCNT++;
        positionCNT = 1;
    }
    br.close();
    while (!wordList.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println(((Word)wordList.removeFirst()).getText());
    }
    return wordList;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that your text file doesn't actually contain the whole address on one line? I've never seen `BufferedReader.readLine()` read more than one line of text...

Comment: @JonSkeet When I print line just after    line = br.readLine()    it prints just the one line but on the print statement afterwards it prints the whole address.

Comment: Do your line has a valid terminator because according to readline() function a line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Comment: It does have a carriage returns at the end of each line. I can't seem to achieve accurate formatting through my comment. I'll post some of the text file in the original question.

Comment: Your `while` loop, loops through the entire file, printing a line at every iteration, is this not intended? Have you stepped through the code to see that the single call to print, actually prints the entire file?

Comment: Why not make an example with reduced scope - just read the file and see if you can read a line at a time. Then introduce the replaceAll() method. It's harder to debug programs that are doing a lot of different things.

Comment: @StewartWirick readline() function will only consider end of line if it finds any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed otherwise it will continue reading

Comment: @ChrisWohlert That is a very good point. Let me check that out real quick.

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaShahid The thing that bewilders me the most is that it is instantiated as a String containing only the first line and prints as such before it does its thing with the whole text file.

Comment: @ChrisWohlert You were right; the file is printing one line at a time. A separate issue, however, is that when printing the wordList at the bottom of the method it prints the words alphabetically. I don't understand how I accomplished this nor was this intended.

Comment: @StewartWirick, Yes exactly, your `wordList` will contain all the words of the file. If you truly only want to work on the first line, you should simply remove your `while(line != null)` loop.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your time! I've gotten some really great insight and I will definitely be back! Is there any way that I can reward you guys for your help with an upvote or anything? (I'm new)

Comment: @StewartWirick, I will make my solution an answer, you can help me ny upvoting and accepting it. :)

Comment: I did but my votes are not yet public. When they become public, you will have one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop, loops through the entire file, printing a line at every iteration. Your wordList will contain all the words of the file. If you truly only want to work on the first line, you should simply remove your `while(line != null)` loop.